# How to export PDF from Excel VBA with a dynamic update

Tags: excel, vba, cube

I have a workbook with several sheets worth of CUBEVALUE functions (and associated CUBEMEMBER functions) that drive a couple of graphs. Further I have a validation list to effectively change the date that CUBEVALUE uses.

What I am trying to do is export to PDF a couple of charts (individual chart pages) as I dynamically update the date.

That is I have a VBA loop that changes for each date that should update (refresh) all the formulas and graphs with new data (estimating some 15,000 CUBEVALUE functions). This is not a quick process and takes time.

The save files have either ##### or blank graphs in them yet if I do the same things by hand I get the correct results

I've tried disabling and enabling Application.EnableEvents, I've tried a Application.Wait with various times including a minutes).

Current code is approx

```
Sub ExportGraphs()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shts(2) As Variant  ' An Array for Worksheet Names

shts(0) = "Chart-QuoteRate"
shts(1) = "Chart-QuoteApp"
shts(2) = "Chart-Penetration"
strPath = "C:\Temp\"
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range
shtChtData.Activate
Set rng = Evaluate(shtChtData.Range("M1").Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In rng
    shtChtData.Range("M1").Formula = c.Formula
    shtChtData.Range("M1").Select
    waitTime = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()) + 1, Second(Now()))
    Application.Wait waitTime

    For x = 0 To UBound(shts)
        strFile = shts(x) & WorksheetFunction.Text(shtChtData.Range("M1").Value, "YYMMDD")
        saveLocation = strPath & strFile
        Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shts(x)).Activate
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, saveLocation, xlQualityStandard
    Next x
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are able to test the refresh state and identify if it is complete then you can use that as the exit condition in a loop.   Something simple like `Do` `DoEvents` `Loop Until refreshIsComplete`. If you still get blank graphs after exiting that loop then you'll know it isn't a result of the refresh and there is something else going on.

Comment: Thanks @ProfoundlyOblivious.  I've found that doing a  `ActiveWorksheet.Calculate` as part of macro code has fixed the problems.  Would seem that you can't rely AutoCalculate to update cube function (must be some weird event thing). Forcing a manual calculate (and also refreshing graphs that depend on the cubevalue results) seems to fix the problems.